# Generic deleteview with condition

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-generic-views

I've been trying to create a Django generic deleteview, to delete an instance of a model.

I however have to check whether it is allowed to delete this item. This is done using a method defined in the model.

So far I've created this:

```
@login_required
def delete_employee(request, pk):

    employee = None
    try:
        employee = Employee.objects.get(pk=pk)
    except:
        pass

    if employee and not employee.empty():
        return render(request, "error.html", None)
    else:
        # Load the generic view here.
```

Is this a decent way to go? And how can I load the generic view there?
I've tried things like `EmployeeDelete.as_view()` but those things don't work.

Or is there a way to check this in the generic view itself?
I've tried that as well, but I wasn't able to load an error page, just throw errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this with a DeleteView you can do this just by overriding the delete method on your inherited view. Here is an example based on what you have said. This is just an example of how you can accomplish it. You might need to tweak it for your exact scenario, specifically the else on can_delete

```
class EmployeeDeleteView(DeleteView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')

    def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        can_delete = self.object.can_delete()

        if can_delete:
            return super(EmployeeDeleteView, self).delete(
                request, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            raise Http404("Object you are looking for doesn't exist")
```

Comment: This works for me. I swapped the error for another view, more suitable for my particular case. Small additional question, would it be possible to throw this error before the confirmation?

Comment: You should be able to override the get method with this. Actually try changing the delete with get and I bet it will work.

Comment: Will try that as soon as I get home. Thank you!